Can't connect to Microsoft 365 to have OneDrive in 24.04
I get to the point where
Mozilla Firefox asks for the permission to open the goa-oauth2 link with System Handler, but when I click "open link" nothing happens. I can connect Google drive and Microsoft personal without problem, when they get to that step they just open the configurations window back up.
This shows up in the debug:

Forget it, this is happening because 24.04 is on gnome 46 not 46.1. I don't know how to close this ask.

Why is Gnome 46 over 46.1 an issue. You could use the answer your own question option at the bottom of the question and say why this is an issue.

I was trying to find people with similar issues and the closest answer i found was that before gnome 46.1 you need a client ID to sync into your Microsoft 365 account


Can't connect to Microsoft 365 to have OneDrive in 24.04

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
There are 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux/Unix platforms:

Via the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business & SharePoint account types and Shared Folders. A Docker container is also available for all major architectures (i686, x86_64, ARMHF, AARCH64). If you need a GUI for onedrive client management use: https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI
Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides the OneDrive 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business account types. Currently does not support Shared Folders or SharePoint.
Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free. Has limitations with SharePoint.
Via non-free clients such as 'insync', 'ExpanDrive'
Via the web browser of your choice

Additionally, whilst GNOME46 also includes a capability to access Microsoft OneDrive, it does not provide anywhere near the capabilities of the first three options.
